# Submit a form using POST request in VueJS

Tags: javascript, post, vue.js

I have an endpoint to submit data using POST request,

```
http://localhost:3000/entry
```

Keys are `fname, lname, age`

I can make a POST request into the given end point and it will create an entry.

I am trying to submit a form using VueJS. But, when I am calling the API within the form, it is not submitting the data. I have checked the network calls and it is not sending any data to the end point.

HTML :-

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.1.16/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


<div id="vueApp">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>
          Dashboard
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="fname">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="fname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="lname" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="age">Age</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="" v-model="age" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" @click="submitEntry">Submit</a>
        <span v-if="ajaxRequest">Please Wait ...</span>
      </div>
    </div> 

    <div>&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="row" v-if="debug">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Table Start -->

    <div class="row">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{fname}}</td>
          <td>{{lname}}</td>
          <td>{{age}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Table END -->

  </div>
</div>
```

script.js :-

```
Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true;

new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',
    data: {
        debug: true,
        fname: '',
        lname: '',
        age: '',
        ajaxRequest: false,
        postResults: []
    },
    methods: {
      submitEntry: function() {
        this.ajaxRequest = true;
        this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/entry', {
              fname: this.fname,
              lname: this.lname,
              age: this.age
            }, function (data, status, request) {
                this.postResults = data;

                this.ajaxRequest = false;
            });
      }}
});
```

style.css :-

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No, no error is showing.

Comment: You might want to try `@click.prevent`, also add a `console.log` inside of `submitEntry()` to see if it is being called.

Comment: Putting the above in a fiddle, I first get an error that a request to `http` is blocked from a `https` context. When I change it to `https`, I get a CORS error, as expected. Is the Vue app served from `localhost:3000`, too?

Comment: I am running the index.html directly to serve the app.

Comment: @DineshAhuja How do you mean? Without a server? Like `file:///......./index.html`? Then AJAX won't work.

Comment: Can you add Vue.http.options.emulateHTTP = true?

Comment: It is not working. Even I am running the index.html from Apache now

Comment: Please post the result of a console.log(this.fname) from inside the http Ajax request

Comment: your .post handler is not an arrow-fn (`x=>...`) so `this` is not bound inside it (or bound to the wrong thing)

Answer (score 4):

You can try this one.

```
axios.post('http://localhost:3000/entry',{ params: { fname: this.fname, lname: this.lname, age: this.age }})
.then(response => this.responseData = response.data)
.catch(error => {});
```

Before using you need to link with Axios CDN

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is a bit old, I just ran into this same issue where **no data was sent to the endpoint** (and this question comes up first in Google).  The problem is that vue-resource's $http.post() defaults to posting data as resource/json and *not* a form.  To post a *form*, set [emulateJSON    to true which will send the "request body as application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type"](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md).

As an aside, the result is a Promise, which means then() should be used to handle the response (as @ribas correctly mentioned).

So the submitEntry() in the example above should be:

```js
      submitEntry: function() {
        this.ajaxRequest = true;
        this.$http.post('http://localhost:3000/entry', {
            fname: this.fname,
            lname: this.lname,
            age: this.age
          }, {
            emulateJSON: true  // <-- This was missing
          }).then(function (data) {  // <-- Handle results like this
            this.postResults = data;
            this.ajaxRequest = false;
          });
      }}
```

Using a completely different library (axios) is fine and actually [recommended by Evan You (creator of Vue)](https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4), but it doesn't address the actual problem using the vue-resource ajax library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
this.$http({method: 'POST', url: URL, data: data})
.then(response => {
   this.postResults = data;
   this.ajaxRequest = false;
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```